# Annotation in Java Why Class type reference is created?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

In the following Code

I am trying to use the annotation I created in another file. I don't understand why I have to write `Class c=test.getClass();` As I already created a object of TEST class then why this is needed? I tried without using this `Class c=test.getClass();` But it showed error

```
public static void showAnnotations()
     // Function to show annotation information
     {
         TEST test=new TEST(); // Instantiating Test class
         try
         {
             Class c=test.getClass(); // Getting Class reference
             java.lang.reflect.Method m=c.getMethod("testMethod"); // Getting Method reference
             // Getting Class annotation
             MyAnnotation annotation1=
               (MyAnnotation)c.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
             // Getting Method annotation
             MyAnnotation annotation2=m.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
             // Displaying annotation information
             System.out.println("Author of the class: "+annotation1.author());
             // Displaying annotation information
             System.out.println("Date of Writing the class: "+annotation1.date());
             // Displaying annotation information
             System.out.println("Author of the method: "+annotation2.author());
             // Displaying annotation information
             System.out.println("Date of Writing the method: "+annotation2.date());
         }
         catch(NoSuchMethodException ex)
         {
             System.out.println("Invalid Method..."+ex.getMessage());
         }
     }
```

Comment: You could just use `TEST.class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Class c=test.getClass();` you don't create a new object (or something similar) you just get the `runtime class` (the class itself) which is used to get/read methods/fields/etc. of the class.

Used if you want to know the class of a field during runtime (example to get the name of the class) in your case a simple `TEST.class` does the same thing since you already know which class you need and use, you don't need to create an instance of it.

---

> public final Class getClass()
>
> Returns the runtime class of this Object. 
>   The returned Class object is the object that is locked by
>   static synchronized methods of the represented class. The actual
>   result type is Class where |X| is the erasure of the
>   static type of the expression on which getClass is called. For
>   example, no cast is required in this code fragment:
>
> Number n = 0;  Class c = n.getClass();

Comment: Thanks a lot for your to the point answer. My concept is clear now

Answer (score 2):

When you call to `getClass` you are using [code reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) which mean you are using in your program data containing information about the program itself.

Yes, you have an object of `TEST` class referenced by `test`. You can use its methods or access its public attributes. That is, you have an instance of `TEST` class which you developed to represent some piece of information using the OOP paradigm.

On the other hand, you need an object modelling your program itself: A instance of a class representing your classes.
Java provides classes modelling information about other classes: The `Class` class.

So you need to ask for an instance of `Class` representing your TEST class. That is your line:

```
Class c=test.getClass();
```

You could have also get this instances using the following line instead:

```
Class c=TEST.class;
```